# Asp.net MVC invoke new request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have a controller action which creates a new Thread for a long running process.

The controller gets it's dependencies via `Ninject`.

The problem is that when the Thread is trying to access the dependencies, the've already been disposed.

Is there a way of making a full new request from inside the `Thread` created, which will execute the long running task, so the dependencies will be re-created?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public HomeController(
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DoLongRunningTask(Guid product_Id)
    {
        // long running action

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            (data) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // _unitOfWork is already disposed when i get here
                    Product product = _unitOfWork.Products.First(p => p.Id == product_Id);

                    // do long running task
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            });

        return new JsonNetResult { Data = new { } };
    }
}
```

Comment: Inject `IResolutionRoot` into the controller, then pass the `IResolutionRoot` from the controller to the task, and then inside the new thread, use the `IResolutionRoot` to retrieve all the dependencies. However, if your dependencies are bound in RequestScope, you will get a problem: There's no request scope in the new thread. You might get away with faking it (it=request) or you might need to adjust your bindings. At least it will immediately show if there is a scoping problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about recreating it when it is null. using `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService`

```
try
{

 if(_unitOfWork==null)
 {
  _unitOfWork=(IUnitOfWork)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IUnitOfWork));
 }
  Product product = _unitOfWork.Products.First(p => p.Id == product_Id);

    // do long running task
}
```

P.S: Not sure will `DependencyResolver.Current` exists at that time